# Straightening rounded lines with Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I have the following problem.

I have taken several pictures of a rectangular box filled with various objects from straight above the center of the box.

I would like the box to appear perfectly rectangular in every picture. Unfortunately even after correcting the lens distortion, the edges do not appear perfectly straight, but slightly rounded outwards. A very small distortion--in fact--but still quite visible by the naked eye. A bit annoying, also because I would like to print the pictures in a large format.

How can I solve the problem with Photoshop?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words...or some help w/ PS, at a minimum.

Comment: Can you post an example? That will help us help you.

Comment: Also: how are you correcting lens distortion?

Comment: As @mattdm says, how are you correcting? PhotoRAW has two methods depending on whether you are working from the RAW file or another format. There's also a separate Filter for Lens Correction. All can produce slightly different results.

Answer (score 1):

Open it in Adobe Camera Raw. There are several ways to do it. One is from Filter menu | Camera Raw filter.

Press Shift+T in order to activate the Transform tool. There you have several modes from which one is Automatic (the 1st one) and Guided aka. Manual (the last one).

Also, you can play with the sliders. I didn't target for perfection but [here is a quick example](https://asceticexperience.com/portfolio/the-aim-of-our-life-and-the-definition-of-sin-in-relationship-with-the-holy-spirit/) on how I corrected such things.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend *PTLens* (US$25), https://www.epaperpress.com/ptlens/ It includes a Photoshop plugin.

It will correct barrel and pincushion distortion using the Exif data. It has an extensive lens database that allows it to automatically apply the proper amount of correction, no guesswork.

Note that you must apply the correction before any cropping or rotating, the database parameters only are relevant to the original un-cropped, un-rotated image.

Also note that the built-in distortion correction in Photoshop is constantly getting better. I use CS5, and PTLens is certainly better than CS5, I can't comment on newer PS versions.